# How to fix white screen areas?

Tags: gnome

I don't know what's happening.  I'll have stuff open and I'll get weird white spots on my screen.  It goes away when I click on it.  How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: what graphic card you use? and why with fallback? please let to know a little more due to common solution is not exist

Comment: nvidia geforce 580

Answer (score 1):

It's not white spots. These are screen wipeouts that happen in many systems when the processor is slow to handle graphics memory.

For example, if you drag a window, the space behind it will turn white.

I recommend upgrading your processor and/or RAM or not doing heavy graphic-oriented multitasking.

Comment: I have Intel Core i7 970 3.20 GHz, EVGA GeForce GTX 580, and 12GB of ram.  I get white spaces without moving anything.

Comment: As you're using Kali Linux, I think it'll be appropriate to consider with their support. For example, there's this group on Facebook that my cousin showed me (and he's an active part of): here's the [link](https://www.facebook.com/groups/KaliLinuxOS/) (you'll need a Facebook account). It's more Windows-friendly in graphics interface, so there may be things we don't understand.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I think it is problem around your currently installed drivers.
By me your system capable to do not use fallback mode **at all** despite the fact that fallback is more hybrid and flexible. Fallback mode uses Ubuntu-community driver. Though your system have adequate power to use Bumblebee Nvidia driver.

Troubleshoot your system by this guide: [***Bumblebee Troubleshooting***](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting)
Read more about [***Bumblebee***](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)